# 100万行昇順・降順ソート時のバグについて

Tags: emeditor

こんにちは。
EmEditor 20.2.2で100万行のURLをソートしたところ、
A-Z、Z-Aでは問題なく処理されるのですが、昇順・降順ソートを選択した場合、
1行目にあきらかに異常な数値が表示されます。

以下は実在しないURLですが

https://google.com/sample/ABC5000000
https://google.com/sample/ABC5000001
……
https://google.com/sample/ABC5999998
https://google.com/sample/ABC5999999

を昇順ソートした場合に、1行目はhttps://google.com/sample/ABC5062500となり、
降順ソートした場合には、1行目がhttps://google.com/sample/ABC5750000となります。

なお、
https://google/sample/ABC5000000
https://google/sample/ABC5000001
……
https://google/sample/ABC5999998
https://google/sample/ABC5999999
の場合は昇順・降順ともに正常にソート可能であり、ピリオドが何かしらの影響を及ぼしているものと存じます。

お手数をおかけしますがご確認のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [並べ替え] ページの各オプションは、どのように設定されているでしょうか? 一度、[リセット] ボタンをクリックして既定にして、問題が再現するかどうか、お試しください。

Answer (score 0):

[EmEditorのFAQ](https://jp.emeditor.com/support/#toggle-id-55)の"変数"のところに「巨大ファイルを開くと、並べ替え（ソート）コマンドが無効になります。並べ替えコマンドが無効になる条件は何でしょうか」という項目があり、

> 並べ替えコマンドが無効になる要因は 2 つあります。
>
> 1. 並べ替えコマンドが有効になるには、[カスタマイズ] ダイアログ ([ツール] メニュー – カスタマイズ) の [高度] タブで、[一時ファイルを使う最小ファイル サイズ] テキスト ボックスに並べ替えしたいファイルのサイズよりも大きい値が指定されている必要があります。
> 2. 32ビット版 EmEditor を使用されている場合、レジストリ エディタで、次のキーを探します:
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareEmSoftEmEditor v3Common
>    MaxReserveBits という REG_DWORD 値を作成し、10進数で 24 (16進数で 0x18) を設定します。既定値は 10進数で 20 (32ビット版EmEditor) または 24 (64ビット版EmEditor) です。この値は、EmEditor が並べ替えられる最大の行数を指定します。24より大きな値を指定することはできません。24が指定されていると、理論的には、最大行数は 16777216 になります。しかし、OS が巨大メモリを割り当てることができない場合、これよりも少ない行数になることがあります。この場合、Windows を再起動して、EmEditor のみを起動して再試行してみることをおすすめします。64ビット版 EmEditor を使用されている場合、既定が 24 なので、この値を設定する必要はありません。

との説明がされています。

使っていらっしゃるWindowsやEmEditorが32bit版なのか64bit版なのかを確認し、必要に応じてレジストリを操作しては如何でしょうか。

[注意！] レジストリの設定を誤ると、最悪の場合システムが起動しなくなるといった問題が起こります。
レジストリエディタの操作に慣れていない場合には、Windowsに詳しい方に手助けをしてもらったほうが良いと思います。

Comment: これは古い情報で、現在のバージョンでは当てはまらないと思います。現在のバージョンでは、巨大ファイルでも、並べ替えは常に有効になります。(無効であれば、メニューがグレーになって選択できない状態になりますが、そのようなことはありません。) 必要に応じてFAQを修正、削除したいと思います。